# convert multiple epoch time to date in sql together

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, timestamp

I am having`a whole mysql table of approx 40,000 rows with a column named 'epoch_time' and there is epoch time in it and I want to convert that whole table's 'epoch_time' to a equivalent  'date' together in a single sql query and I'm doing this is in php_my_admin . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an Oracle PL/SQL component to go with that tag?

Comment: I add plsql as a tag because I'm thinking that there will be a use of plsql in execution as I've also tried it.

Comment: Have a look at the `from_unixtime` function.

Comment: Have a look at [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994889/). And remove the plsql tag, [it's an Oracle thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808876/).

Comment: ok but how am I convert all those  epoch_time together and insert it into same table with a new column (let's say - 'date') which is having a date parallel to that epoch_time.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the *values* of the `epoch_time` column? Your comment on my answer says it is `VARCHAR()`. What's in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by epochtime you mean UNIX-style timestamps, that is, number of seconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z`. If my guess is wrong, so is the rest of my answer.

First you add a new column to the table.

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN datestamp DATETIME AFTER epochtime;
```

This names the new column `datestamp` and puts it right after `epochtime` in the list of columns.

Then you update the whole table to populate the new column from the old using [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). Omitting the `WHERE` clause makes the update work on the whole table (careful!).

```
UPDATE mytable SET datestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(epochtime);
```

Finally, if you wish you can drop the old column.

```
UPDATE TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN epochtime;
```

If I were you I'd try all this on a copy of your database to ensure it is correct before doing it on your production database.

If your epochtime values already have the `TIMESTAMP` data type, they are already stored internally as UTC (f/k/a GMT) times. The update operation I suggested will convert them to local time according to the settings on your server.

If your application has users in multiple time zones, you may wish to keep using the `TIMESTAMP` datatype: it honors time zone settings. If your epoch times are stored in an `INT` column, you can create your new column with the `TIMESTAMP` rather than `DATETIME` type by substituting this line for the first one in my instructions above.

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN datestamp TIMESTAMP AFTER epochtime;
```

Comment: I will definitely try this. Thanks

Comment: { epochtime} in my table is in varchar and when I'm applying this - {UPDATE mytable SET datestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(epochtime);} it isn't changing the values in the datestamp column showing {null} by default.

Comment: it works I've done a little change in the query i.e. `UPDATE mytable SET datestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(epochtime\1000000); ` and it works perfectly.

Comment: This query `UPDATE mytable SET datestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(epochtime\1000000);` is giving the time in `GMT+05:30` but I want that it in `GMT` then what changes should I have to do in the query.