# Anonymous PL/SQL blocks in Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm new on MySQL, I'm using MySQL workbench 8.0 on Windows 10 OS.

My question is very easy (and maybe a little naive..): are anonymous PL/SQL blocks permitted on MySQL 8.0?

In the past, I used them a lot on Oracle databases, but in MySQL it seems no possible.

Many thanks anyone who can answer!

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808876/pl-mysql-does-it-exist/9809225

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language built-in into the Oracle DBMS. MySQL is another DBMS. It has nothing that comes even close. It does have stored procedures, but they consist of mere SQL plus a SET command for variables plus some control flow commands (IF/THEN/ELSE, LOOP, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are anonymous PL/SQL blocks permitted on MySQL 8.0?

No, sorry to say.

PL/SQL is an Oracle table server thing. MySQL understands it about as well as I understand Urdu, that is not at all. From the point of view of us users, of the great curses of the database industry is that stored code from one kind of server doesn't work on another.

The makers of expensive database software love this incompatibility because it locks their customers in.